# How to fix 'Kafka Offset commit failed on partition: The request timed out'

Tags: apache-kafka

I suddenly got exceptions of type in production Kafka

```java
ERROR[pool-XX-thread-YY] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=someclientid, groupId=somegroup] Offset commit failed on partition SomeTopic-SomePartition at offset SomeOffset: The request timed out.
```

This occurred for 3.5 seconds from a lot of different services (clients) (different threads\different topics\different partitions) and than just self healed...
The offset commit configurations is 5 second auto-commit for all those clients.

Couldn't track anything from kafka broker logs except of some re-balancing right of one group (out of 10 had that issue) which is normal when heart-beating fails, in the metrics server I can see some spikes of commit latency which is the symptom I guess and some TCP spikes on 1 broker (out of 3)

How can I start investigate it? what can cause such an issue? where should I look when things like that is occurring?

Attaching photos of some graphs here:

**TCP Spike in server-3**
[image: TCP Spike in server-3]

**Commit latency spike**
[image: Commit latency spike]

**Group syncs**
[image: Group syncs]

**Heartbeats**
[image: Heartbeats]